# Should we disable links for very-low-rep users?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, hyperlinks, spam

Considering:

- The overwhelming majority of spam on SO is posted by new users who have joined solely to post their "question" or "answer", almost always have a reputation of 1, and have not posted (and will not post) anything worthy of upvotes.
- Spamming becomes much less useful when you can't tell people where to go, or if your marks have to actually put in effort to go there.
- We already ask that a post (whether question or answer) include the relevant information within it, rather than depending on links to third parties.
- We already disable images for very-low-rep users.

Would it be worth the inconvenience to disable outbound links for users with very low rep (say <15), and have them show up as plain text instead?  A user could still include a URL; it just wouldn't be clickable, and they couldn't hide a different URL behind a link tag.  And since that makes it more work for people answering the question to visit the linked page, it seems to me the answerers would be even more likely to insist the question follow the guidelines already in place.

Comment: @RichardTingle: They could still post the *URL* of an image.  It just wouldn't be clickable til someone edits, at which point they'd make it an image anyway.

Comment: I've seen a lot of legitimate first post links (usually to images). Equally will a plain text URL be that much less effective than a clickable one. Most of the spam doesn't seem to be "tricking" the user. In fact it is blatently "Buy gucci hadbags" so they'll still copy paste if they would have clicked

Comment: @RichardTingle: Copy/pasting is extra work.  I'd be less likely to go through the effort of pasting a URL than click a link.

Comment: The community usually responds to spam flags very quickly, I don't think it's worth the cost of hurting legitimate new users.

Comment: About half of the spam posts I see aren't littered with links, but phone numbers and this wouldn't help against that spam at all. First posts, late answers and spam flags should be enough.

Comment: @3ventic'sShadow: I don't know if i've ever seen spam on SO with a phone number.

Comment: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966108/husband-wife-solution-bengali-babaji91-9166007251) @cHao.

Comment: Not on SO so much, but most of the other SE sites get their fair share of baba ji love advice, complete with phone number to call (invariably +91 xxxxxxxx)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Baba is one of the highlights of my day.

Answer (score 16):

There's a balance to maintain between locking down abuse and still allowing new users to make good, well-researched posts.

After all, we could eliminate nearly ALL the spam by just requiring a few reputation points in order to do *anything* on the site - but at that point, we're blocking all the good stuff too.

A good case-in-point is images, which are not only a tool for spammers<sup>1</sup>, but also for trolls and various other abusers. They're also *really* useful on any site that depends on visual communication to some degree, whether that's posting [an image of your design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) or of [that plant you can't recognize](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

We don't actually block images from new users *everywhere*. On Stack Overflow, the risk of abuse is much, much higher than the potential benefit of allowing them, so they're blocked - but on most other sites, new users can post images right off the bat.

By the same token, the value of *allowing* links generally outweighs the cost of dealing with spam<sup>2</sup>. On most sites, the number of links you can post straight away is limited, but on some, links are considered so essential to a good answer that even this limit is waived. It's plausible that we might one day have a site that *would* block all links from new users, but at present I'd be hard-pressed to think of a topic where this wouldn't be a serious liability.

<sub><sup>1</sup>yes, if you block links then you get *images* of URLs. And URLs carefully spelled out to be recognizable by humans but not machines. Not kidding.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>which wouldn't go down that much anyway, since spammers are perfectly happy to pay some 3rd-world cyborg to keep trying variations on input text until it goes through.</sub>

Comment: And what if the URL is still there?  I'm not talking about banning the mention of URLs -- just the automatic turning of them into clickable links.

Comment: You're assuming spammers even care about that.

Comment: I assume spammers care about clicks and google juice.  Once their links aren't clickable, they lose quite a bit of both.  For some reason, that little extra work required to copy/paste a URL, or even right-click and pick "go to url", can be a dealbreaker for stuff you know is spam.  But for a legitimate question, someone's going to be more likely to check it out and generally even edit the link in.

Comment: When your cost per impression is very, very close to zero, I suspect you can afford to be a bit lax with the accounting on your click-through rates. And we nofollow all these anyway, so anyone doing this for Google juice is already screwed. For reference, one of the most persistent spammers on SE currently doesn't bother with URLs at all, preferring one of a number of throw-away phone numbers.

Answer (score 8):

While this might function as intended, it makes the UX for legitimate new users that much more difficult.  We already make them

- Register for an account to do most everything (or anything beyond reading on a couple of sites)
- Don't let them post images [(on some sites)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229288/182513),
- Don't let the comment
- Don't let them upvote
- And probably a few more things I'm not thinking of.

The whole point to spam prevention is to make it inconvenient for spammers without significantly impacting the user experience for everyone else.

Seeing Spam is annoying but the community, in general, does a pretty good job of removing it on new posts, that I don't think this is a major concern.

However, I would be in favor of a limited implementation of this idea.  Low/No rep users should not be allowed to edit clickable links into posts (except for their own posts).  Even with review, there seems to be more occurrences of these making it through and once they are edited in, they can go weeks before getting found (if they even get discovered)

Answer (score 0):

The system is self managing.

If a spam link is added to an unpopular post, it never gets upvoted, never gets read, and does the would-be spammer no good.  Eventually someone will flag it as spam, and the normal moderation system works its magic.

If a spam link is added to a popular post, its quite quickly flagged and deleted.

In both cases the links are `nofollow` so that search engines never use the site's google ranking for the link.

The system works well right now. There's no need to block links.

Comment: Opposition resistance forces do always work on the hardest downvotes and live exclusively there. Their concern and special interest is of non-viewed nondescript pages with 0 (no attention) "-" could be of an interesting opinion with knowledge that's considerably differs from most "grey matter" which just moves the site (and is just togetherd ppl enlarging entropia).