# Child protection: adding recognition filters to block obvious offensive content related to pornography

Tags: feature-request, status-review, legal, offensive, age

**We've had yet another unsuitable post on [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour).**

The title was innocent enough:

> I'm think of making steam punk/fansty hybrid do you have any
> suggestions

The body of the question contained this unsuitable text:

> Porn movie in which individuals excrete fecal matter and play with, rub it over each other, or eat it. People who indulge in this are called Scat lovers, Scatophiliacs, and Coprophiliacs Commonly found in Brazilian, Japanese, and German pornography. Two girls One Cup was a scat porn video in Brazil.

Then two *very* graphic scatological pornographic pictures which I'll not reproduce here.

**Issue:**

- It's plainly unsuited to any stack on the network, there are restrictions for this sort of content which make it [illegal to produce or possess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography_laws_by_region#Europe) in many countries including in parts of the EU.
- It is not age-suitable for the [minimum age requirements of joining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/why-cant-i-use-stack-exchange-if-im-under-13-years-old-or-if-im-under-16-yea) to become a member here even in areas where it's legal.
- Age verification is not sought on becoming a contributor to the network.
- Viewing this content is possible even without joining.
- I immediately flagged as unsuitable - after 35 minutes it was still viewable. It's since been edited to obscure the content, but not everyone can do that.
- A report to [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) using the [appropriate syntax](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Commands#privileged-commands) can be almost immediately effective, but isn't known about by many members or passers-by. The post can "hang around" for an indeterminate length of time.
- Possible (? not sure when that can happen) indexing by search engines permanently associating this content with the network.

**Feature requests:**

- Is there the possibility of the rather obvious textual content triggering the post to be unavailable to not-logged-in viewers and non-curators until the post can be cleared as suitable?
- Image recognition technology is capable of identifying such things, could a filter by picture be implemented to put suspect pictures/posts containing them in a holding pattern until they can be cleared?
- If not already implemented, please create a filter preventing indexing of such content until it's been vetted by a minimum of one trusted member or some other exception filter.

There's plenty of well-developed image recognition filters emerging on the market, and if the company is prepared to invest in child-protection, (I think they should, it's going to be big) and SE being an early adopter would be a marketing point in their favour.

Further, see: [How can we get spam deleted faster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324617/how-can-i-get-spam-deleted-faster), [should-we-disable-links-for-very-low-rep-users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229285/should-we-disable-links-for-very-low-rep-users/229288#229288).

Comment: See my [question on getting spam deleted faster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324617/323179) and [why images are allowed on some sites and not others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229288/323179).

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much we can do except flag the heck out of it, and get a CM to nuke the images

Comment: @ARogueAnt. yeah images are problematic, but I've edited thousands of screenshots into programming questions asked by 1 rep users that were legitimate and the question would have been senseless without the screenshot. Taking that functionality away would make life a lot more difficult for legitimate users who are just joining the network. (The image recognition approach might be better than outright forbidding uploads by 1 rep users.)

Comment: At present, I agree, however there's plenty of well-developed image recognition filters emerging on the market, and if the company is prepared to invest in child-protection, I think they should, it's going to be big, and SE being an early adopter would be a marketing point in their favour. @JourneymanGeek

Comment: @bad_coder Actually I'd be good with having uploads reputation gated (again) they were before - especially as a per site flag.

Comment: I think Worldbuilding generally has a problem in this area. I remember seeing at least two posts in HNQ that contained graphical descriptions of torture or other mutilation practiced in the world OP was building.

Comment: We've [discussed it](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7973/55743) a fair bit and adopted some somewhat explicit standards. The nature of worldbuilding is such that they're often on-topic of course, but there is a line. @idmean

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think that would work best if there were some sort of queue in which uploads by new users could still be approved by those willing to filter through them. Just thinking from a Biology.SE standpoint, preventing uploads would be a problem for our species-ID questions. Though on the other hand it would help with all the people who post screenshots of their homework, so probably a net positive...

Comment: Who posted this (a new user or an established one)? Was it an attempt at a post for WB or just regular spam/abuse (possibly plagiarizing the title)?

Comment: @BryanKrause hence it being per site. You *could* have it enabled or disabled for new users

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Got it, I missed that part of the discussion.

Comment: @Laurel It was a new user, plagiarising the title in a generic sort of way, the body was pure shock-trolling, no spam-link present.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow The  Kid Wizard. Better.

Comment: @W.O. no problem, I thought a lot about it actually, as sometimes it's good to "throw the truth in the face" as the saying (?) goes.

Comment: @Philippe 8 months after being marked for review, any updates? This request is pretty complex so personally not building my hopes very high.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard - without giving away methods, I can say that our Trust and Safety team is working on functionality to address this problem. I obviously don't want to give away too much to avoid reverse engineering.  With that said, the folks who do this sort of thing are very creative, and most sites are unable to 100% abuse-proof themselves.  However, we know that measures currently in place are fairly effective, along with the nature of the platform and its mechanics discouraging this type of posting.  In short: we're working on it, but please keep flagging.

Comment: @Philippe awesome, thanks. If you can share this in an answer would be even better, so people would know something is done. As a comment, not many will notice. Thanks again! :) (Also, maybe we need [tag:status-in-progress] tag, as none of the existing status tags fit)